# Can't get the actual Like number of a URL in Facebook

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-fql

The like_count of link_stat table now include the number of user liked any comments or re-shares of that URL.

Does anyone know how can I get the actual Like of a URL itself?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know only gives you shares+likes count of a URL. so, there is no way you can get only likes count.